# how to create folder when user registers and log in him after registration in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a separate folder for each user when they register and log them in after the folder creation. I don't know how to do this. I tried something that creates the folder but redirects to the same registration page saying email already exists.(i.e It creates the folder and registers the user in the DB but instead of logging in it tries to register the user again).

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

        return \Storage::makeDirectory($data['name']);
        //The above creates folder.


}
```

I know i should return the user to log in. I don't know how to do both together.

Comment: place the code that I have given as an answer, and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the folder and then return created user instance like it does Laravel:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    \Storage::makeDirectory($data['name']);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: exactly i did this now and it works and i was about to answer my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
              'name' => $data['name'],
              'email' => $data['email'],
              'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
           ]);
    auth('your-guard-name')->login($user);
    //this logs the user into the application

    return \Storage::makeDirectory($data['name']);
    //The above creates folder.


}
```

Comment: when i register , i get this error 
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, boolean given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\ctohire\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 63 and defined. 

But it creates the folder and logs in when i reload the error page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think creating a new folder for each user is a good practice. If you want to store user related stuff and identify them, you can map the `file_name` to `user_id` or append some user_id identification to the file_name. However in your scenario, please try the following code.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

//create user and store it in variable called user
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

//make the folder with user_id, since the duplication can happen in name. Here the path is defined and the folder name is created with user id and the folder permission 755 is given
$makeDir = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory/'.$user->id , 0775);

//Then auth login user
Auth::login($user);

//Then return to dashboard or new view.
return redirect('/dashboard');

}
```